# passing multiple value 1 name javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I was working with my thesis, I got stumble when I tried to store a tag to some uploaded file

I've found some javascript to help me create tags on upload page.

```
$("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters

      if(txt) {
        $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(),value:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
        $("<input/>", {type:"hidden",value:txt.toLowerCase(),name:"Tags", insertBefore:this});
      }
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

what if I want to pass multiple tags to my upload controller with this js?

I've tried using input type hidden, but it only pass 1 value at a time,
and also, I cant delete the input value, so if I'm mistaken and delete the tag, the hidden input doesn't get deleted too.

pls, help me, Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly you're trying to send more tags to the server under the same `name=""`

You can do that by changing the name `Tags` with `Tags[]` like:

```
$("<input/>", {
    type:         "hidden",
    value:        txt.toLowerCase(),
    name:         "Tags[]",
    insertBefore: this
});
```

On the serverside Tags will be an `array`